# Generate instance with different string parameters in verilog

Tags: verilog

When I was config pll_reconfig module in Quartus II, the generate for statement in design have to specify different string parameter (filenames) to different instances.
I have tried these code:

```
genvar i;
generate 
   for (i=0; i<2; i=i+1) begin:u
      rom #($sformatf("mif%d.mif",i)) U(
         //signals connected.
      );
   end
endgenerate
```

It is said that the code is not synthesizable.
How can I specify variable string parameter in generate for block?

Comment: Would you not be better creating an array of strings and just selecting s[i], or I think you can concatenate strings with `{}` some thing like {"mif", i, ".mif"}.

Comment: but loop variable "i" must be convertted into string, before that.

Comment: Strings are not synthesizable. Can you share your `rom` module with us? It will help us understand how you intend to use the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but on a system that did not support $sformatf. My solution is a little dirty but may help others:

```
genvar i;
generate
  for (i=0; i<10; i=i+1)
  begin
    mymodule #(.NAME("NAME0" + i) instance(.RESET(mreset) ... );
  end
endgenerate
```

This works, I believe, by treating the string "NAME0" as a number (a 40-bit number). By adding i, you just increase the value by i and the result is the last ASCII char changes. Luckily '0' + i gives you '1', '2', '3' etc

The obvious flaw is this only works for 0-9, however there is a simple extension using divide and modulo arithmatic:

```
mymodule #(.NAME("NAME00" + (256 * (i / 10)) + (i % 10) ) ) ...
```

---

As a side note, I ran into issues using string concatenation {"NAME", i} because Verilog was treating i as 32-bit value so the string ends up as:

```
NAME   1
```

due to the extra 'unwanted' 24 bits which equate to 3 null characters